# Parasitic network usage?

Tags: java, android, upload, connection

My app will be running in the background and uploads data to the server from time to time. Everything works fine, except that I want my app **NOT** to upload data to the server on its own by turning on network services. Instead, I want it to only start the upload process when another app or service has started a connection. In some words, I wanna be parasitic to the other app.

I know for a fact that this can be done in Android, however I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try registering for the broadcast intent WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION, via a BroadcastReceiver. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that right now. but I want the upload to still happen even if my app is closed, sort of queuing packages ready for sending. I know there's a way to do that, just couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Do you mean that you want your app to queue up the packages, and then for some always-running service to actually send those packages when a connection occurs (regardless of whether or not the app is running)? If so, I would suggest creating a Service (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), and pass messages from your app to the service. Then you have the Service register for the broadcast intent, and do the uploading.